# How can we know if the removeClass operation is success or Failed ??

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var value =   $("p").removeClass("intro");

  });
});
</script>
<style>
.intro
{
font-size:120%;
color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p class="intro">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Remove the "intro" class from all p elements</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi ,

This is my program for removing some class

My question is that how can i know if the removeclass operation is success or failure ??

`$("p").removeClass("intro");` can have any return type set for this ??

Comment: You can use `$("p.intro").length`

Comment: you can use `.hasClass` function. for example `$("p").hasClass("intro");`

Comment: You can use hasClass()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.hasClass()` to verify that:

```
$("p").hasClass("intro")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can verify whether the node still has the class after you've performed `.removeClass()` on it with the `.hasClass()` function:

```
if ($('p').hasClass('intro')) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $("p").removeClass("intro");
  if ($("p").hasClass("intro"))
  {
     alert("class not removed !");
  }

  });
});
</script>
```